# aidl is missing when importing an Tango example project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, google-project-tango

I downloaded the [Tango SDK](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/download-terms?f=TangoSDK_Nash.jar) and [examples](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java) for Java. After importing the Area Learning example into Android Studio, I went into the libs folder and added the SDK as a library. Then, I tried to build the project, but get the error "Error:Execution failed for task ':tangoUtils:compileReleaseAidl'. aidl is missing." After looking this up, I found that multiple people had this issue when using Build Tools Version 23.0.0 rc1 and that switching to 22.0.1 would help, but I still have the same error. Below is my build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.projecttango.experiments.javaarealearning"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':tangoUtils')
    compile files('libs/tango_java_lib.jar')
    compile files('libs/TangoSDK_Nash.jar')
}
```

Comment: You reference another module in your build file -- is that one using build tools 23? What about any other modules?

Comment: Thanks! It turns out the other module was still using build tools 23.